# Expandable list view with customized scrollbar in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to build a widget like this one that we can find in Word :

[image]

[image]

So, there is a list view using a specific scrollbar with 3 buttons and no scroll.

When you click on the last button at the bottom right, a new list view with a classic scrollbar is shown over the previous list view (hidden when losing focus). So basically, the smae behavior as the one in Word.

We are already capable of displaying a list view with custom content.
My main concern is how to build the widget in the first image: the list view with the custom scrollbar (3 buttons, no scroll)?

What is the proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

At first hide the default scroll-bar by calling the `QAbstractScrollArea::setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff)` method.

Then create your three buttons on the left side and connect the `QPushButton::clicked()` signals to some slots where you just scroll your list by calling the `QAbstractItemView::scrollTo(index)`, `QAbstractItemView::scrollToBottom()` or `QAbstractItemView::scrollToTop()`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're implementing a subclass of `QAbstractListView`.

I don't believe you need a custom scrollbar - just put the scrollbar and the button into a `QVBoxLayout`; hide the button once it's checked (you could even connect its `toggled()` to its `setHidden()` for that).

Answer (score 0):

While it is correct that you could just build a custom widget consisting of a view with hidden scrollbars and add the buttons to the layout, connecting the signals/slots needed to provide the proper actions, you can also consider to implement your own `QScrollBar` class. `QListView` is derived from `QAbstractScrollArea`, which provides `setVerticalScrollBar()` so you can just set an object of it to be used by the view. The integration of scroll area and scroll bar should be much more straightforward this way, but you'll have to do the painting of the scroll bar's content yourself, or put a layout and the buttons in there (`QScrollBar` derives from `QWidget`, and you'll have to reimplement `paintEvent()`).